# Replace manifest intent-filter for extended class in flavor

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

In my app, flavor Lite has it's own manifest and overrides the main's SplashActivity with SplashActivityLite. The main manifest has a launcher intent-filter for SplashActivity. But since the SplashActivityLite also has a launcher intent-filter, 2 app icons are installed.

I have tried adding tools:node="replace" and tools:node="merge" to activity tag SplashActivityLite.
I have tried adding tools:node="replace" to each attribute in the intent-filter (action and category tags).

How can override the intent filter of the main manifest when the class names are not the same?

Comment: Do you need `SplashActivity` to be usable in the flavor (and just not appear as a launcher icon)? Or is `SplashActivity` simply not needed for this flavor?

Comment: It is used, yes, but in the sense that SplashActivityLite extends SplashActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment, what you seem to be aiming for is a merged manifest for this flavor where `SplashActivityLite` exists but `SplashActivity` does not.

In the flavor's manifest, I think you would need to have two `<activity>` elements (at least, in terms of relevance to this problem):

- One would point to `SplashActivityLite` and be normal, with your `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`
- The other would point to `SplashActivity` and have `tools:node="remove"` to get rid of it from the merged manifest

Alternatively, you could:

- Have the `SplashActivityLite` normal manifest entry in the flavor
- In `main`, have `android:enabled="@bool/useMainSplash"` on `SplashActivity`
- In `main`, define `useMainSplash` to be `true`
- In the flavor, define `useMainSplash` to be `false`

That would keep the manifest entry for `SplashActivity` but disable it so it would not be launchable.

In either approach, the `SplashActivity` class should be unaffected, so `SplashActivityLite` can extend it without issue.

Comment: I used the first approach, but both are correct and work